# Comprobar si es un numero primo o no en C

Tags: c

Tengo este programa en donde se almacena la cantidad de números que quieres ingresar y también puedes digitar esos números, el problema sucede que quiero que me indique si los números digitados son *primos* o *compuestos*, he estado buscando información, pero aun así no he podido solucionar ese problema.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    
    int i,x,a,b,numeros[50];
    int suma=0;
    a=0;
    
    printf("¿Cúantos números vas a ingresar?:");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    for(i=0;i<x;i++){
        printf("Número %d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&numeros[i]);
    }
   
   
    printf("\n====================================\n");
    printf("\nDETERMINAR QUE NUMERO ES PAR O IMPAR:\n");
    for(i=0;i<x;i++){
        printf("\nNúmero %d es: \n",i+1);
        
        if(numeros[i] %2==0){
    
            printf("\nEl número es PAR\n");}
        else{
            printf("\nEl número es IMPAR\n");}
            
    }
    for(i=0;i<x;i++){
        if(numeros[i]%numeros[i]==0 && numeros[i]%0==0)
        printf("\nnumero %d es:",i+1,"es primo");
        else
        printf("\nnumero %d es:",i+1,"es compuesto");
    }
    
    
    
    printf("\n====================================\n");
    printf("\nDETERMINAR LA SUMA\n");
    
    for(i=0;i<numeros[i];i++){
        
        suma+=numeros[i];
        
    }
        printf("\nSUMA TOTAL ES:%d\n",suma);
     

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Un número primo solo es divisible entre 1 y el mismo, luego lo único que tienes que hacer es un bucle para que comience a dividir el número por todos los que van desde 2 hasta el anterior al numero. Si pruebas 7 divides por 2,3,4,5,6. Si en alguna división el resto es cero, el número no es primo.
La forma más simple sería esto:

```
bool esPrimo (int n)
{
  int divisor = 2;
  bool seguir = true;
  while (divisor < n and seguir)
    {
      seguir = n % divisor != 0;
      divisor++;
    }
 return seguir && n>1;
}
```

Claro no es muy eficiente, si el número es grande se toma su tiempo. Para mejorarla se podrían aplicar los algoritmos de divisibilidad.
**EDITO**
Si por ejemplo el número leído está en numeros[i] (como para los pares) pues es fácil:

```
    if(esPrimo(numeros[i])){
       printf("El número %d SI es primo", numeros[i]);
    }
    else{
       printf("El número %d NO es primo", numeros[i]);
    }
```

Ojo, el 1 no es primo.

Comment: y como seria para que se muestren si son primos o no con printf?,disculpa si me pregunta es muy obvia pero recién soy principiante  en la programación.

Comment: Ya lo tienes, es lo mismo que para los pares: compruebas y en caso de que sea primo los escribes.

Comment: Si quieres mejorar tu algoritmo investiga sobre qué es la división tentativa

Comment: Efectiamente existen algoritmos bastante más complejos que aplicar la definición, pero más eficaces computacionalmente hablando.

Answer (score 0):

Un algoritmo más efectivo para comprobar si un número es primo consiste en ver si el número es divisible por números impares desde el 3 hasta la raíz cuadrada del número.

```
#include <math.h>

bool esPrimo(int n){
    if (n < 2) return false;
    if (n % 2 == 0) return n == 2;

    int raiz = (int)sqrt(n);
    for (int i = 3; i < raíz; i += 2){
        if (n % i == 0) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Si quisieras generar una lista de números primos, puedes utilizar la [Criba de Eratóstenes](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criba_de_Erat%C3%B3stenes).